Swift property conforming to ObjC protocol has no member 'publisher'
In a larger ObjC/Swift-mixed codebase I have an ObjC protocol MyObjCProtocol <NSObject> that other ObjC classes need to conform to. It declares a string property @property (copy) NSString *myString.
Now, one of my Swift objects has a property conformsToObjCProtocol that is declared conforming to this protocol:
let conformsToObjCProtocol: MyObjCProtocol

This all works well.
But when I try to observe myString using Combine like this:
let cancellable = conformsToObjCProtocol.publisher(for: \.myString).sink { print($0) }

I get an error Value of type 'any MyObjCProtocol' has no member 'publisher'.
I believe it should work because MyObjCProtocol is declared conforming to NSObject. I did add MyObjCProtocol.h to the bridging header too so that's not it. I can't rewrite the protocol in Swift because I need ObjC classes to conform to it. What can I do about this?

The Objective-C protocol is imported into Swift as a protocol that requires conformance to NSObjectProtocol. It does not require the conformer to inherit NSObject.
If you declare the property like this:
let conformsToObjCProtocol: MyObjCProtocol & NSObject

then this can be observed using a NSObject.KeyValueObservingPublisher.
NSObject.KeyValueObservingPublisher(
    object: conformsToObjCProtocol, keyPath: \.myString, options: []
).sink { ... }

The publisher method unfortunately cannot be used here because of how it is declared. The declaration requires that you call it on a concrete type.

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that even though your protocol MyObjCProtocol inherits from NSObject, Combine doesn't automatically recognize the properties for publishing. The publisher(for:) method is an extension provided by Combine for objects that support key-value observing (KVO), which doesn't directly apply to protocols in Objective-C.
Here is a solution in Swift to address this problem:

Create an extension for NSObject: You can create an extension for NSObject that provides a publisher method for KVO-compatible properties.

Use AnyObject instead of MyObjCProtocol: Since Combine requires a concrete reference and your protocol is just an abstraction, you need to use AnyObject and ensure that your concrete object conforms to the protocol.


Here is an example of how you can do this:

Extension for NSObject:

import Combine
import Foundation

extension NSObject {
    func publisher<T>(for keyPath: KeyPath<NSObject, T>) -> AnyPublisher<T, Never> {
        Publishers.KVObservablePublisher(object: self, keyPath: keyPath)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}


Observing the property:

import Combine

// Ensure your concrete object is an NSObject and conforms to the protocol
let objcObject: AnyObject = conformsToObjCProtocol as AnyObject

// Force cast objcObject to NSObject to use the extension
guard let nsObject = objcObject as? NSObject else {
    fatalError("The object is not an NSObject")
}

// Create the publisher and subscribe to it
let cancellable = nsObject.publisher(for: \.myString).sink { newValue in
    print(newValue)
}

Ensure that myString is properly exposed for KVO in your Objective-C class. This should resolve the issue and allow you to observe changes in the property using Combine.

Thanks for the great in-depth answer! Are you sure about 'KVObservablePublisher'? Compiler complains about it and I can't find any symbol with that name anywhere ...
